# Как создать правило в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Структура директорий

```
web
- bar
  - index.php //вы в bar
  - .htaccess
- foo
  - index.php // вы в foo
  - .htaccess
```

Как сделать htaccess что бы при запросе bar/page запустился index.php из foo?

Такой вариант:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page)
RewriteRule ^page(\/?.*)$ ../foo/index.php$1 [L]
```

Говорит:
Not Found
The requested URL /bar/page/ was not found on this server.

Такой:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page)
RewriteRule ^page(\/?.*)$ ../foo/$1 [L]
```

открывает эту же страницу в bar

Comment: дак вы как то попробовали может написать правило? типа там `RewriteRule ^bar/page$ foo/index.php [L]`  или что-то подобное? для общего аксесса в `web`

Comment: @teran Я пробовал так:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page)
RewriteRule ^page(\/?.*)$ ../foo/$1 [L]`
Не сработало

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ответ:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page(/.*)?$ /foo/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess, который должен лежать в корне (в каталоге web):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page$  /foo/index.php
```

Если есть доступ к конфигу апача, то можно и так для сайта в `bar`:

```
Alias /page /www/foo/
```

Comment: В web нельзя класть .htaccess, веб-сервер смотрит в bar

Comment: Тогда надо чтобы другой веб-сервер `another_web_server` смотрел в foo, и в .htaccess (который в bar) делать внешний редирект `RewriteRule ^bar/page$  http://another_web_server/index.php`